# How to convert number to next higher multiple of five?

Tags: c#

I am coding a program where a form opens for a certain period of time before closing. I am giving the users to specify the time in seconds. But i'd like this to be in mutliples of five. Or the number gets rounded off to the nearest multiple.

if they enter  1 - 4, then the value is automatically set to 5. 
If they enter 6 - 10 then the value is automatically set to 10.

max value is 60, min is 0.

what i have, but i am not happy with this logic since it resets it to 10 seconds.

```
 if (Convert.ToInt32(maskedTextBox1.Text) >= 60 || Convert.ToInt32(maskedTextBox1.Text) <= 0)
                    mySettings.ToastFormTimer = 10000;
                else
                    mySettings.ToastFormTimer = Convert.ToInt32 (maskedTextBox1.Text) * 1000;
```

Comment: just a side note, if you are doing the conversion to int multiple times I would create a local variable so you only need to perform that operation once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what about this:

```
int x = int.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text)/5;
int y = Math.Min(Math.Max(x,1),12)*5; // between [5,60]
// use y as the answer you need
```

Comment: -1 So bad that I had to downvote, even though I usually try to avoid doing so.

Comment: Guys, why is this bad? x will have the divisor. y will have a value in the range {5, 10, 15,..., 60}. isn't that what the question asked?

Comment: It is a horribly complex way of determining if something is divisible by 5. This is why the modulus operator exists. Not to mention the part about fiddling around with the maskedTextBox1.Text value....that is way too UI specific.

Comment: I was trying to help the person who asked the question to do what s/he eventually wanted to do. did you read the full question?

Comment: @morpheus - please make an edit to your question - i want to reverse my downvote. Your answer perfectly addresses the body of the question if not the title. Good job. (i cannot upvote unless you make an edit)

Comment: @downvoters - I think you may be mistaken. Morpheus has provided code to do exactly what the OP asked for in the body of the question. Seconds in intervals of 5, min 0 max 60. The UI reference is in context with the question. I made the same mistake in downvoting but upon closer look wish to reverse this decision.

Comment: +1 because you solved the problem stated as op. to being down voted by  users who could not read the question only the title.

Comment: @Hogan - lol, I guess there is that. I wonder if it would let me un-downvote if I edited it?

Comment: Add 4 to the parsed int before dividing 5 and you've got my vote.

Comment: @Sky Sanders : It would -- the joy of 2k+

Comment: @morpheus - outis has a good point, you could fold in the desire (mentioned in a comment) to round up by adding 4.

Answer (score 23):

use the [Modulus Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

```
if(num % 5 == 0)
{
  // the number is a multiple of 5. 
}
```

Comment: OMG the modulus, COMPLETELY FORGOT ABOUT THAT. I knew i knew the answer before asking. Thanks! by the way, know a way to "round" off to the next 5? lol

Comment: If the number isn't a multiple of 5 and you want to go to the next closest multiple, then do: num += (5 - (num % 5)).

Actually, instead of testing the number to be a multiple of 5, you can just do that and know that the result will be the value, or the next multiple.

Comment: For your purpose, however, an _integer_ division, followed by a multiplication seems more appropriate, specifically: `delayInSeconds = (((int) userInput + 1) / 5 ) * 5`  (followed by the filter on 0-60 range.  You're not so much interested in the fact that modulo isn't 0 than to "push" the value to the next multiple of 5 whether it needs it or not.

Answer (score 6):

```
5 * ((num - 1) / 5 + 1)
```

Should work if c# does integer division.

Comment: You need to first subtract 1 from `num`, otherwise you'll round up multiples of 5 to the next multiple of 5. I'm guessing this is why someone downvoted you.

Comment: +1 outis. With that minor error fixed, this is a really simple way to do exactly what the OP asked.

Answer (score 4):

For the higher goal of rounding to the upper multiple of 5, you don't need to test whether a number is a multiple. Generally speaking, you can round-up or round-to-nearest by adding a constant, then rounding down. To round up, the constant is one less than *n*. Rounding an integer down to a multiple of *n* is simple: divide by *n* and multiply the result by *n*. Here's a case where rounding error works in your favor.

```
int ceil_n(int x, int n) {
    return ((x+n-1) / n) * n;
}
```

In dynamic languages that cast the result of integer division to prevent rounding error (which doesn't include C#), you'd need to cast the quotient back to an integer.

Dividing by *n* can be viewed as a right-shift by 1 place in base *n*; similarly, multiplying by *n* is equivalent to a left-shift by 1. This is why the above approach works: it sets the least-significant digit of the number in base *n* to 0.

```
2410=445,  2510=505,  2610=515
((445+4 = 535) >>5 1) <<5 1 = 505 = 2510
((505+4 = 545) >>5 1) <<5 1 = 505 = 2510
((515+4 = 605) >>5 1) <<5 1 = 605 = 3010
```

Another way of zeroing the LSD is to subtract the remainder to set the least significant base *n* digit to 0, as Jeras does in his comment.

```
int ceil_n(int x, int n) {
    x += n-1;
    return x - x%n;
}
```